# WSO2 APIM 4.2 - Circuit Breakers: not able to edit the API definition in the Publisher

Tags: wso2-api-manager, circuit-breaker

I am trying to implement Circuit Breaker and i am trying to do so according to this documentation: https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/deploy-and-publish/deploy-on-gateway/choreo-connect/endpoints/resiliency/circuit-breakers/#enable-circuit-breakers-for-api-endpoints

For some reason if I try to modify the API Definition under WSO2 Publisher -> API Configurations -> API Definition, it reverts back automatically after saving it. also when it try to save and deploy, when I go back to the page it seems the changes are not saved.

Am I doing something wrong or are more people experiencing this? By the way if I try to modify the description of the API, that works also after saving. Also tried to export and import the yaml file but also that does not help.

Thanks!